# expect().toEqual() failed if returned array is set with new Array() constructor

Tags: jestjs

I'm testing a function that divides the array into many subarrays base on the given chunk size, the test failed if variable chunk is set with `new Array()` constructor? but with run time array `[]` the test pass? any idea on the error.

`index.js`:

```js
function chunk(array, size) {
  const chunked = new Array(); // change this to [] the test pass

  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i += size, j++) {
    chunked[j] = array.slice(i, i + size); // remove index j and use push() method test pass
  }

  return chunked;
}
```

Unit test:

```js
const chunk = require('./index');

describe('Chunk function', () => {
  test('should correctly divide an array of 10 elements with chunk size 2', () => {
    const chunked = chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2);
    expect(chunked).toEqual([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]);
  });
});
```

Comment: `chunk[j] = ...` should be `chnk[j] = ...`, but that's probably just a typo.  What error are you getting?  It passes either way for me..

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Did you get any error?

`index.js`:

```js
function chunk(array, size) {
  const chunked = new Array();

  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i += size, j++) {
    chunked[j] = array.slice(i, i + size);
  }

  return chunked;
}

module.exports = chunk;
```

Unit test:

```js
const chunk = require('./index');

describe('Chunk function', () => {
  test('should correctly divide an array of 10 elements with chunk size 2', () => {
    const chunked = chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2);
    expect(chunked).toEqual([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57850379/index.spec.js
  Chunk function
    ✓ should correctly divide an array of 10 elements with chunk size 2 (9ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.547s
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

dependencies:

```
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
```